# Supervised dedupe rule finds duplicate when manually run but not automatically

Tags: duplicate-contacts, dedupe-rules

I'm running CiviCRM 5.51.0 (the problem was the same with 5.50.4) on WordPress 6.0

- I defined a supervised dedupe rule using personalized fields which is properly working (i.e. finds duplicates on one of the 3 selected fieds) when manually run.

[image]

- When duplicate contacts are created or edited via the administrative CiviCRM interface, they are not detected by this supervised rule.

Would you have any tricks? Is it a known bug; I was not able to find any info on this?

Many thanks for your help

Christophe

Comment: i confirmed this problem on dmaster site. I will ask on https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/

Comment: Wasn't aware of this problem but possibly because the fields are custom fields

Comment: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/ufaad9hqobgh8yctn5mgu5mpsh @petednz-fuzion question

Comment: I can confirm the same issue when using a custom field in the supervised rule.

Comment: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3901